# Ubuntu 12 cronjobs won't run

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, vps

I'm trying to create backup cronjobs. When I run the same command in the console, its working. But when the cronjobs will be executed in crontab nothing happens.

Manually line:

```
sudo /bin/tar -czf /var/backup_websites/weekly/all_websites.tar.gz /var/www
```

Cronjob line:

```
14 11 * * * sudo /bin/tar -czf /var/backup_websites/weekly/all_websites.tar.gz /var/www
```

I did already change the timezone, this can't be the problem. I think it is a problem with my permissions, but I did set permissions on 777 for the backup folders (backup_websites and weekly).

[Screenshot crontab](http://prntscr.com/cwahwz)

Comment: Leave out the "sudo" and run the job from root's cron.

Comment: I had it first without sudo, didn't work aswell. With "root's cron" you mean from the root? But it is already at the root, right? Sorry, I'm new with linux.

Comment: Using what command (or into what file) are you placing this cron line?

Comment: In the crontab (command: crontab -e) I uploaded a screenshot to be more clear.